# Is there a way to add 2 countries next to each other instead of 1 on each row by using CSS?

Tags: html, css, web-frontend

### What I want to do

I'm trying to add 2 countries to each row parallel while keeping the sizes of each country box the same, currently, I have one.

### What I tried

I tried adjusting the flexbox properties and making the size smaller but it didn't work.

### Image

[image: demo]

### My code

```css
.country-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

/* Style for each country div */
.country {
  flex: 0 1 calc(50% - 1em); /* Adjust the width calculation */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border: 3px solid #212020;
  margin: 1em; /* Add margin to create space between country divs */
  padding: 1em; /* Increase padding if needed for spacing within each country */
  text-align: center;
  background-color: beige;
}

/* Style for the flag image */
.flag {
  /* No need for additional styles here */
}

/* Style for the country name */
.country h2 {
  margin: 5px 0;
}

/* Style for the Wikipedia link */
.wiki-link {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="country">
    <img class="flag" src="country_flags/ws.png" alt="Flag of Samoa"/>
    <h2>Samoa</h2>
    <p>Currency: Euros (EUR)</p>
    <p>Regions: Atua
    , Fa'asaleleaga
    , Tuamasaga
    </p>
    <a class="wiki-link" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samoa" target="_blank">Wikipedia</a>
    </div>

<div class="country">
    <img class="flag" src="country_flags/pk.png" alt="Flag of Pakistan"/>
    <h2>Pakistan</h2>
    <p>Currency: Rupee (PKR)</p>
    <p>Regions: Azad Jammu and Kashmir
    , Balochistan
    , Gilgit-Baltistan
    , Islamabad
    , Khyber Pakhtunkhwa
    , Punjab
    , Sindh
    </p>
    <a class="wiki-link" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pakistan" target="_blank">Wikipedia</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

1. First wrap the html code in `.country-container`. with this the flex style will work. But now, the smaller content like the samoa country will get squished.
   [image]
2. Add `flex:1;` to `.country` which says the the divs should take equal space. This will fix the squish and let it take equal space
   [image]
3. Add `gap: 10px` to create a gutter.
4. Finally remove `margin` from `.country` as it might create spacing issues.

### Code

```css
.country-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 10px;
}

/* Style for each country div */
.country {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border: 3px solid #212020;
  padding: 1em;
  /* Increase padding if needed for spacing within each country */
  text-align: center;
  background-color: beige;
}

/* Style for the flag image */
.flag {
  /* No need for additional styles here */
}

/* Style for the country name */
.country h2 {
  margin: 5px 0;
}

/* Style for the Wikipedia link */
.wiki-link {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="country-container">
<div class="country">
    <img class="flag" src="country_flags/ws.png" alt="Flag of Samoa"/>
    <h2>Samoa</h2>
    <p>Currency: Euros (EUR)</p>
    <p>Regions: Atua
      , Fa'asaleleaga
      , Tuamasaga
    </p>
    <a class="wiki-link" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samoa" target="_blank">Wikipedia</a>
  </div>

 <div class="country">
    <img class="flag" src="country_flags/pk.png" alt="Flag of Pakistan"/>
    <h2>Pakistan</h2>
    <p>Currency: Rupee (PKR)</p>
    <p>Regions: Azad Jammu and Kashmir
      , Balochistan
      , Gilgit-Baltistan
      , Islamabad
      , Khyber Pakhtunkhwa
      , Punjab
      , Sindh
    </p>
    <a class="wiki-link" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pakistan" target="_blank">Wikipedia</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: since i have 20 countries total, do i put them all under the same country container or create seperate ones for each of the 2?

Comment: @Shaz if ya have 20 countries then make 10 `.country-container` and put 2 `.country` in each of them. So like put 2 countries in their own separate container with `class="country-container"`

Comment: If ya think my answer satisfies your need, accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap both countries in a container and apply flex

```css
.country-container {
  display: flex;  
  justify-content: space-between;
}

/* Style for each country div */
.country {
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border: 3px solid #212020;
  margin: 1em; /* Add margin to create space between country divs */
  padding: 1em; /* Increase padding if needed for spacing within each country */
  text-align: center;
  background-color: beige;
  width:40%;
}

/* Style for the flag image */
.flag {
  /* No need for additional styles here */
}

/* Style for the country name */
.country h2 {
  margin: 5px 0;
}

/* Style for the Wikipedia link */
.wiki-link {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class ='country-container'>
<div class="country">
    <img class="flag" src="country_flags/ws.png" alt="Flag of Samoa"/>
    <h2>Samoa</h2>
    <p>Currency: Euros (EUR)</p>
    <p>Regions: Atua
    , Fa'asaleleaga
    , Tuamasaga
    </p>
    <a class="wiki-link" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samoa" target="_blank">Wikipedia</a>
    </div>

<div class="country">
    <img class="flag" src="country_flags/pk.png" alt="Flag of Pakistan"/>
    <h2>Pakistan</h2>
    <p>Currency: Rupee (PKR)</p>
    <p>Regions: Azad Jammu and Kashmir
    , Balochistan
    , Gilgit-Baltistan
    , Islamabad
    , Khyber Pakhtunkhwa
    , Punjab
    , Sindh
    </p>
    <a class="wiki-link" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pakistan" target="_blank">Wikipedia</a>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: On large screen, The samoa container gets squished

Comment: seems to work fine here.  Does it work in the snippet for you?  The problem is probably in another part of your code that you haven't supplied

Comment: Yeah there was the problem when I tried it myself on codepen with full width view, In my answer, I even posted the image

Comment: did you add the 40% width to the countries?

Comment: I think the 40% width thing is not good for creating gaps and consistent widths. since as screen width scales up, the gap between will also scale up... so using `flex` is better along with `gap`